# Calculating no. Of Subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

What is the number of subgraph in a linear tree having n nodes?
For 1 vertex I have  1 subgraph
For 2 vertex I have 3 subgraph
For 3 vertex I have 6 subgraph
For 4 vertex I have 10 subgraph
And so on....
Is there any generalise formula to calculate it

Null graph(has no vertices and no edges) is not included subgraph.

Comment: up to isomorphism? And does it have to include every vertex?

Comment: No ismorphism,and it's not necessary to include all vertices

Comment: OK, then how did you get 2 subgraphs for 2 vertices? There's one containing one vertex, one containing the other, one containing both, and possibly one containing neither if you allow it. That's four.

Comment: Yes you are right let me edit the question,but how a graph with no edge and no vertices can be a subgraph?

Comment: it just depends on whether you allow it to be a subgraph or not. But for example we would generally like the intersection of subgraphs to be a subgraph. So then the "empty graph" as it is called has to be a subgraph.

Comment: Is it necessary to have a empty subgraph?

Comment: If you don't want to include it in your question, that's fine. Often people don't include it. You just need to specify exactly what you mean by subgraph here!

Comment: I assume he means the path graph $P_n$ (i.e $n$ dots arranged on a line with an edge between consecutive vertices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the graph you are considering is $P_n$, the path with vertices $\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}$ and edges $\{ \{ i, i+1 \} | 1 \le i \le n-1 \}$, and you are interested in the number of connected nonempty subgraphs.

Suppose $G \subseteq P_n$ is a connected nonempty subgraph.  Let $a$ be the smallest vertex appearing $G$, and let $b$ be the largest vertex appearing in $G$.  Since $G$ must be connected, there has to be a path from $a$ to $b$ in $G$.  However, the only such path in $P_n$ is $a - (a+1) - (a+2) - ... - (b-2) - (b-1) - b$, and so all vertices and edges between $a$ and $b$ must be included in $G$ as well.  Since $a$ and $b$ are the smallest and largest vertices in $G$ respectively, there cannot be anything else in $G$.

Hence $G$ is determined uniquely by $a$ and $b$, and so the number of connected subgraphs of $P_n$ is equal to the number of possible values for the pair $(a,b)$.  Note that we must have $1 \le a \le b \le n$, since $a$ cannot be larger than $b$.

There are two possibilities.  If $a = b$, then we have $n$ options for what this common value should be.

If $a < b$, then we can choose any two distinct numbers between $1$ and $n$, and set the smaller one to be $a$ and the larger one to be $b$.  Hence there are $\binom{n}{2}$ such cases.

In total, that leaves $n + \binom{n}{2} = \binom{n+1}{2} = \frac12 n(n+1)$ connected nonempty subgraphs of $P_n$.

For example, if $n = 4$, we should have $\frac12 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 = 10$ such subgraphs.  Writing $G_{a,b}$ for the subgraph with lowest vertex $a$ and largest vertex $b$, these are (in your notation):
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
G_{1,1} = (1) & G_{1,2} = (1,2) & G_{1,3} = (1,2,3) & G_{1,4} = (1,2,3,4) \\
& G_{2,2} = (2) & G_{2,3} = (2,3) & G_{2,4} = (2,3,4) \\
& & G_{3,3} = (3) & G_{3,4} = (3,4) \\
& & & G_{4,4} = (4)
\end{array}.$$

Comment: What n/2 cases ? if I have n=4,n/2=2,then what 2 denotes

Comment: Where are you seeing  $n/2$? $\binom {n}{2} $ is a binomial coefficient, equal to $\frac {n (n-1)}{2} $.

Comment: Suppose that $a_n$ denotes the number of subgraphs in $P_n$. Could you please, prove, or give a hint, for the formula
\begin{align*}
a_n = a_{n-1}+\sum_{0 \leq i \leq n-1}a_i
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The number of subgraphs of a linear tree is $2^n$ by induction (if you include the empty graph).

After reading the comments it seems you are considering subgraphs that do not necessarily contain all vertices.

Comment: Can you prove it for n=3

Comment: Where does this formula come from?  It doesn't match the initial values given in the problem.  Also note that selecting $i$ vertices from a linear tree on $n$ vertices does not in general give you a linear tree on $i$ vertices.

Comment: For n=3,(1),(2),(3),(1,2),(2,3),(1,2,3) These are the subgraph set

Comment: @Shagnik you are correct, doesn't work with subsets since you no longer get necessarily a linear tree.

Comment: @AnshulNegi It looks like you are asking for the connected subgraphs of the path - is that correct?  Such a subgraph must contain some first vertex $a$, with $1 \le a \le n$, and a last vertex $b$, with $a \le b \le n$.  In order for there to be a path from $a$ to $b$, every vertex (and edge) in between must be included as well.  This means that every subgraph corresponds to a choice of $a$ and $b$ such that $1 \le a \le b \le n$.  To count these: given $a$, how many choices are there for $b$?  Now add these up for all possible values of $a$.

Comment: @Shagnik could you make it more clear by giving an example